# How do I get the 'this' element in Backbone click event?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing

When I click something, I'd like to do something to that element (i.e. add a class), though I don't believe that this 'this' element in my event handler is actually that element. Here is a sample bit of my code:

```
var ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "firstthing": "firstthing",
    },

    firstthing: function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});

var ApplicationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('body'),

    events: {
        'click #something': 'displayFirstThing'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.router = new ApplicationRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    },

    displayFirstThing: function(){
        this.router.navigate("firstthing", true);
    },
});

new ApplicationView();
```

I'm wanting to add the class of 'active' to #something. I'll have more events that will have different classes etc, but looking to get some of the basics down now.

Also, accepting any suggestions on code structure!

Comment: You might try checking the `argument`s to the displayFirstThing function. Backbone might be passing the `event` object, in which case you could try using `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: This is a good tip @GregBurghardt. So I see that `event.CurrentTarget` is the element I'm looking for, but is this being passed into my `firstthing` function?

Comment: @GregBurghardt or I guess I'm wondering, is there a way to use `event.currentTarget` in my `firstthing` function?

Comment: The `event.currentTarget` property should be the target of the delegated event. In your case, I think `event.currentTarget.id` should be `"something"`. Your code could be: `event.currentTarget.classList.add("active")`. Is your displayFirstThing method getting the event object as an argument? I'm just curious. I haven't used Backbone outside of experimenting with it.

Comment: You're right, my `event.currentTarget.id` is `something`. I used `console.log(event.currentTarget.id)` in my `displayFirstThing` function and I get the value `something`. And it does work to use `event.currentTarget.classList.add("active")` in my displayFirstThing method, but now I'm wondering what the purpose of my `firstthing` method is at all? Like why not have all that code in my `displayFirstThing` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone passes the event object as the first argument to the callback from which you can use the `currentTarget` property to work with the element that received the event. E.g.

```
var ApplicationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('body'),

    events: {
        'click #something': 'displayFirstThing'
    },

    // ... other code

    displayFirstThing: function( event ){
        $( event.currentTarget ).addClass( 'active' );
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store the elements that you want to access in view properties.

i.e.

```
var ApplicationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('body'),

    events: {
        'click #something': 'displayFirstThing'
    },

    render: function() {
      // render the view
      // store the link element in a property
      this.$something = this.$('#something');
    },

    displayFirstThing: function(){
        this.$something.addClass('someclass');
    },
});
```

Comment: do you think it is more appropriate to do these types of actions in the view or router?